# Why does putting filter() in different positions give different histograms?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, tidyverse

Below is are 2 chunks of code for comparison - note that the position of filter(n() >= 100) is different:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)
movielens %>%
  group_by(userId) %>%
  filter(n() >= 100) %>%
  summarise(mean_rating = mean(rating)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mean_rating)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=30, col="black")
```

and

```
movielens %>%
  group_by(userId) %>%
  summarise(mean_rating = mean(rating)) %>%
  filter(n() >= 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(mean_rating)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=30, col="black")
```

These two pieces of code give two different-looking histograms. Why is this so? Shouldn't they both do the same thing?

Comment: No, try to use the first two rows of the first script (not `library()` of course), and the first three rows of the second, and you'll see the difference, where it's applied `filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

After aggregate functions like *summarise*, the "grouping" has no meaning and is removed, and n() returns the number of rows for the full *dataframe* instead of per userId, compare the output of these two commands:

```
movielens %>%
  group_by(userId) %>%
  summarise(mean_rating = mean(rating)) %>%
  mutate(n = n())
# # A tibble: 671 x 3
# userId mean_rating     n
#    <int>       <dbl> <int>
# 1      1        2.55   671
# 2      2        3.49   671
# 3      3        3.57   671

movielens %>%
  group_by(userId) %>%
  summarise(mean_rating = mean(rating)) %>%
  group_by(userId) %>% 
  mutate(n = n())

# # A tibble: 671 x 3
# # Groups:   userId [671]
# userId mean_rating     n
#    <int>       <dbl> <int>
# 1      1        2.55     1
# 2      2        3.49     1
# 3      3        3.57     1
```

Answer (score 1):

after summarise() the data frame is not a grouped object and the filter doesn't do anything whereas in the first example you apply the filter on the grouped object (only 263 userIDs satisfy your condition)and then pipe the result into summarise(). Hope this helps.